# Google Sheets formula to merge multiple columns into one cell, including headers / label

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to combine multiple columns in a Google sheet into one cell, including headers / labels. My input sheet looks like this:

| Name | Description | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foo |  | val 1 | val 2 | val 3 |
| Bar |  | val x | val y | val z |

And I want to concatenate the values in each column into a single cell, including the headers for each value. Desired output:

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Foo | Col 1 val 1 Col 2 val 2 Col 3 val 3 |
| Bar | Col 1 val x Col 2 val y Col 3 val z |

This formula concatenates the columns into one, however it doesn't include the headers (note that `char(10)` produces a linebreak):

```
=TEXTJOIN(char(10),true,B2:E2)
```

I can produce a similar result using [`REDUCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597) (I can't believe I'm writing a reducer in a Google Sheet):

```
=REDUCE("", B2:E2, LAMBDA(accumulator, current_value, CONCATENATE(accumulator, current_value, char(10))))
```

However the lambda function doesn't seem to provide the index of the current iteration, so I'm not sure how to grab the column name above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this formula**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( 
 QUERY({"Description"; 
        TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
        IF(B2:D="",,","&B1:D1&","&B2:D&",")),"",9^9)),",",CHAR(10)))},
        " Where Col1 is not null" )       )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try the old way:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:D="",,"×"&B1:D1&"×"&B2:D&"×")),,9^9))), "×", CHAR(10))))
```

[image]

---

or in one cell if that's what you want:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(REDUCE(, B1:D1&CHAR(10)&B2:D3&CHAR(10), 
 LAMBDA(a, c, a&c&CHAR(10)))))
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't put it in my question - I'll edit - I also have columns before the "description" column I want to preserve. I see this formula overwrites the entire row. Is it possible to make it only operate on the current columns and the ones to the right?

Comment: @AndyRay not sure I understand your request. can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I edited the question - I want to preserve the first n columns, I added a "Name" column as an example. I don't want to overwrite it, I want to merge everything to the right of the name column

Comment: @AndyRay what you mean is that the first formula provided in the above answer is not suitable because it ends with D column and does not continue to the last column you have there? is that right?

Answer (score -1):

Using your current `TEXTJOIN()` formula you can just include the Column Headers with the dollar sign ($) which means absolute reference so it will not change when copied/dragged down to rows below.

**Try:**

```
=TEXTJOIN(char(10),true,C$1,C2,char(10),D$1,D2,char(10),E$1,E2)
```

Drag down to rows.

**Result:**

[image]

Refer to this link for more info on Absolute Reference: https://www.lido.app/tutorials/absolute-reference-on-google-sheets

Comment: This will work for my exact question, for my real world use case I need to apply this formula to a few dozen sheets all of which have different numbers of columns I want to collapse into the cells. This is slightly less convenient than the other answers since I'd have to hard code each column reference for every formula.

Comment: Sorry if that didn't help. Since there was no accepted answer yet I assumed you wanted a solution more aligned with your current formula. From your reply, does that mean your concern is resolved by others answers? As a general rule in StackOverflow if your question is answered, please accept an answer which works best for you. This lets other members from the community with the same concern as you know that it can be resolved. Upvotes are also appreciated but not needed. @AndyRay